# How to force an update of a subcomponent?

Tags: javascript, lit

Lit Documentation says:

> When called with no arguments, `requestUpdate()` schedules an update,
> without calling a `hasChanged()` function. But note that
> `requestUpdate()` only causes the *current* component to update. That
> is, if a component uses the code shown above, **and** the component
> passes `this.myArray` to a subcomponent, the subcomponent will detect
> that the array reference hasn't changed, so it won't update.

So how to force an update of a subcomponent (even if the subcomponent's attribute doesn't change)?

```
render() {
  return html`
    <ul>
      ${this.myArray.map(
        (item) => html`
          <li>
            ${item.text}
            <my-subcomponent foo="${item.bar}"></my-subcomponent>
          </li>
        `
      )}
    </ul>
  `;
}
```

Edit: [Repro in Lit Playground](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-IHtcbiAgICAgICAgaXRlbS5jb2xvcmVkID0gIWl0ZW0uY29sb3JlZDtcbiAgICAgIH1cbiAgICApO1xuICAgIHRoaXMubXlBcnJheSA9IFsuLi50aGlzLm15QXJyYXldO1xuICAgIGxvY2FsU3RvcmFnZS5zZXRJdGVtKCdteUFycmF5JywgSlNPTi5zdHJpbmdpZnkodGhpcy5teUFycmF5KSk7XG4gIH1cblxuICByZW5kZXIoKSB7XG4gICAgcmV0dXJuIGh0bWxgXG4gICAgICA8dWw-XG4gICAgICAgICR7dGhpcy5teUFycmF5Lm1hcChcbiAgICAgICAgICAoaXRlbSkgPT4gaHRtbGBcbiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxsaT4ke2l0ZW0udGV4dH0gKDxzdWItY29tcG9uZW50IGlkPSR7aXRlbS5pZH0-PC9zdWItY29tcG9uZW50Pik8L2xpPlxuICAgICAgICAgIGBcbiAgICAgICAgKX1cbiAgICAgIDwvdWw-XG4gICAgICA8YnV0dG9uIEBjbGljaz0ke3RoaXMuY2hhbmdlTXlBcnJheX0-Q2hhbmdlIG15QXJyYXk8L2J1dHRvbj5cbiAgICBgO1xuICB9XG59XG5cbmN1c3RvbUVsZW1lbnRzLmRlZmluZSgnbWFpbi1jb21wb25lbnQnLCBNYWluQ29tcG9uZW50KTsifSx7Im5hbWUiOiJzdWItY29tcG9uZW50LmpzIiwiY29udGVudCI6ImltcG9ydCB7aHRtbCwgY3NzLCBMaXRFbGVtZW50fSBmcm9tICdsaXQnO1xuXG5leHBvcnQgY2xhc3MgU3ViQ29tcG9uZW50IGV4dGVuZHMgTGl0RWxlbWVudCB7XG4gIHN0YXRpYyBwcm9wZXJ0aWVzID0ge1xuICAgIGlkOiB7dHlwZTogTnVtYmVyfSxcbiAgICBteUFycmF5OiB7dHlwZTogQXJyYXl9XG4gIH07XG5cbiAgY29uc3RydWN0b3IoKSB7XG4gICAgc3VwZXIoKTtcbiAgICB0aGlzLm15QXJyYXkgPSBKU09OLnBhcnNlKGxvY2FsU3RvcmFnZS5nZXRJdGVtKCdteUFycmF5JykpO1xuICB9XG5cbiAgcmVuZGVyKCkge1xuICAgIHJldHVybiBodG1sYFxuICAgICAgICAke3RoaXMubXlBcnJheS5tYXAoXG4gICAgICAgICAgKGl0ZW0pID0-IGh0bWxgXG4gICAgICAgICAgICA8c3BhbiBzdHlsZT1cImNvbG9yOiAke2l0ZW0uY29sb3JlZCA_IGl0ZW0uY29sb3IgOiAnYmxhY2snfVwiPiR7dGhpcy5pZCA9PT0gaXRlbS5pZCA_IGl0ZW0udGV4dCA6ICcnfTwvc3Bhbj5cbiAgICAgICAgICBgXG4gICAgICAgICl9XG4gICAgYDtcbiAgfVxufVxuXG5jdXN0b21FbGVtZW50cy5kZWZpbmUoJ3N1Yi1jb21wb25lbnQnLCBTdWJDb21wb25lbnQpOyJ9LHsibmFtZSI6ImluZGV4Lmh0bWwiLCJjb250ZW50IjoiPCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw-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-XG4gIDxzY3JpcHQgdHlwZT1cIm1vZHVsZVwiIHNyYz1cIi4vbWFpbi1jb21wb25lbnQuanNcIj48L3NjcmlwdD5cbjwvaGVhZD5cbjxib2R5PlxuICA8bWFpbi1jb21wb25lbnQ-PC9tYWluLWNvbXBvbmVudD5cbjwvYm9keT4ifV0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the lit.dev playground repro, I was able to identify some issues that should resolve your issue.

Before jumping into the various fixes, why is the subcomponent not re-rendering? LitElements render as a function of their properties & state. If properties don't change, they don't re-render.

The subcomponent has two reactive properties, `myArray` and `id`. `myArray` is only set once on construction from localstorage and never updated - so it will never trigger an update. The `id` number also never changes for a given subcomponent so will never trigger an update. Because neither properties change, the subcomponent doesn't re-render.

#### Option 1: Pass the new array to the sub-component.

[Fix 1 in Lit Playground](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-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-PC9zdWItY29tcG9uZW50Pik8L2xpPlxuICAgICAgICAgIGBcbiAgICAgICAgKX1cbiAgICAgIDwvdWw-XG4gICAgICA8YnV0dG9uIEBjbGljaz0ke3RoaXMuY2hhbmdlTXlBcnJheX0-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-IGh0bWxgXG4gICAgICAgICAgICA8c3BhbiBzdHlsZT1cImNvbG9yOiAke2l0ZW0uY29sb3JlZCA_IGl0ZW0uY29sb3IgOiAnYmxhY2snfVwiPiR7dGhpcy5pZCA9PT0gaXRlbS5pZCA_IGl0ZW0udGV4dCA6ICcnfTwvc3Bhbj5cbiAgICAgICAgICBgXG4gICAgICAgICl9XG4gICAgYDtcbiAgfVxufVxuXG5jdXN0b21FbGVtZW50cy5kZWZpbmUoJ3N1Yi1jb21wb25lbnQnLCBTdWJDb21wb25lbnQpOyJ9LHsibmFtZSI6ImluZGV4Lmh0bWwiLCJjb250ZW50IjoiPCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw-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-XG4gIDxzY3JpcHQgdHlwZT1cIm1vZHVsZVwiIHNyYz1cIi4vbWFpbi1jb21wb25lbnQuanNcIj48L3NjcmlwdD5cbjwvaGVhZD5cbjxib2R5PlxuICA8bWFpbi1jb21wb25lbnQ-PC9tYWluLWNvbXBvbmVudD5cbjwvYm9keT4ifV0)

The only change I've made is to pass `myArray` to `sub-component` explicitly, (note `.myArray=${this.myArray}`):

`<li>${item.text} (<sub-component id=${item.id} .myArray=${this.myArray}></sub-component>)</li>`

This works because now when the parent updates `this.myArray`, the parent passes this new array to the sub-component. The sub-component then notices that the reactive property `myArray` has changed and a render is scheduled.

#### Option 2: Only pass the item to the sub-component

This is a larger change, but more maintainable and simpler. Instead of passing both the array and item id to each sub-component, only pass the item that the sub-component cares about.

This does less work on the sub-component because each sub-component doesn't need to loop through the whole array to find the element that it cares about.

Working [fixed playground from repro](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-IHtcbiAgICAgICAgcmV0dXJuIHsuLi5pdGVtLCBjb2xvcmVkOiAhaXRlbS5jb2xvcmVkfTtcbiAgICAgIH1cbiAgICApO1xuICB9XG5cbiAgcmVuZGVyKCkge1xuICAgIHJldHVybiBodG1sYFxuICAgICAgPHVsPlxuICAgICAgICAke3RoaXMubXlBcnJheS5tYXAoXG4gICAgICAgICAgKGl0ZW0pID0-IGh0bWxgXG4gICAgICAgICAgICA8bGk-JHtpdGVtLnRleHR9ICg8c3ViLWNvbXBvbmVudCAuaXRlbT0ke2l0ZW19Pjwvc3ViLWNvbXBvbmVudD4pPC9saT5cbiAgICAgICAgICBgXG4gICAgICAgICl9XG4gICAgICA8L3VsPlxuICAgICAgPGJ1dHRvbiBAY2xpY2s9JHt0aGlzLmNoYW5nZU15QXJyYXl9PkNoYW5nZSBteUFycmF5PC9idXR0b24-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-PC9zY3JpcHQ-XG48L2hlYWQ-XG48Ym9keT5cbiAgPG1haW4tY29tcG9uZW50PjwvbWFpbi1jb21wb25lbnQ-XG48L2JvZHk-In1d).

This approach requires a change in `changeMyArray`. Instead of mutating the items, new items need to be returned.

```
  changeMyArray() {
    this.myArray = this.myArray.map(
      (item) => {
        return {...item, colored: !item.colored};
      }
    );
  }
```

Breaking down that example. `this.myArray.map` already returns a new array so the array spread is not required. Within the `map` each item that is modified must return a new object. This is similar to how [redux works](https://redux.js.org/usage/troubleshooting#never-mutate-reducer-arguments) and the linked article may provide more helpful details.

Now the parent render function can be updated to pass the item directly to the subcomponent with: `<li>${item.text} (<sub-component .item=${item}></sub-component>)</li>`.

Now when the `item` changes, the sub-component automatically re-renders.

#### Option 3: Manually calling a method that triggers an update

I would not recommend this over option 2, but wanted to show how you *could* trigger the sub-component to re-render.

Working sample: https://lit.dev/playground/#gist=fb38e52bc4d35dd74485407eb19db84f

There are two changes. In the parent, 'main-component', `changeMyArray` method I've added a loop that calls a method on each sub-component:

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('sub-component')
        .forEach(component => component.refresh())
```

And on the sub-component I've defined `refresh` as:

```
  refresh() {
    this.myArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myArray'));
  }
```

Because the sub-component now has the new version of this.myArray from localstorage it will trigger a re-render.

The cons of this approach and why option 1 or 2 is better:

- Each sub-component needs to manually parse the array out of localstorage.
- This approach requires manually managing when renders happen instead of letting the state flow down through properties.

There's a video called [Event communication between web-components](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9mxtnoy9Qw) by Elliott on the Lit team that discusses state and events further.

Comment: Thank you! While this actually solves my issue, I'm still wondering if there really isn't a straight forward solution to just tell the subcomponent to update. Neither the array nor the item actually need to be passed as the subcomponent retrieves them from local storage anyway.

Comment: Added a third option answer which uses localstorage as the source of truth.